# Loading child nodes on demand in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have firebase database as follows where I have child node Photos which may have multiple values as you can see. Now I am pulling all the data in Ionic page when it loads where I want to show other details in list and photo count. So I don't really want to bring all photos values while pulling the data but only count. When user actually clicks on photo count I want to pull photo details and open another page and show photos there. Can someone help me with this as I am completely new to firebase? I am using firebase SDK.

[image: Firebase db structure]

Comment: No one faced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question to help other people who may be looking for it.

Instead of nesting photos inside parent. I have flattened the database structure by creating "Photos" node separately parallel to its parent and kept its parent ID along with URL which will help me pulling all photos of node I am looking for.